# sqlite .backup command fails when another process writes to the database (Error: database is locked)

Tags: sqlite

The goal is to complete an online backup while other processes write to the database.

I connect to the sqlite database via the command line, and run

```
.backup mydatabase.db
```

During the backup, another process writes to the database and I immediately receive the message

```
Error: database is locked
```

and the backup disappears (reverts to a size of 0).

During the backup process there is a journal file, although it never gets very large. I checked that the journal_size_limit pragma is set to -1, which I believe means its unlimited. My understanding is that writes to the database should go to the journal during the backup process, but maybe I'm wrong. I'm new to sqlite and databases in general.

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Use a `.timeout 1000` (Or some other number of milliseconds) first?

Comment: Shawn, this should be an answer instead of just a comment! :)

BTW, the complete syntax is: `sqlite3 source.db ".timeout 1000" ".backup backup.db"`

Answer (score 1):

If the sqlite3 backup writes "Error: database is locked", then you should use

`sqlite3 source.db ".timeout 10000" ".backup backup.db"`

See also [Increase the lock timeout with sqlite, and what is the default values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66909180/increase-the-lock-timeout-with-sqlite-and-what-is-the-default-values) about default timeouts (spoiler: it's zero) and now with backups solved you can switch SQLite to WAL mode (it supports multiple writers!).

//writing this as an answer so it would be easier to google this, thanks guys!