# Increase the lock timeout with sqlite, and what is the default values?

Tags: database, sqlite, perl

Well known issue when many clients query on a sqlite database : *database is locked*
I would like to inclease the delay to wait (in ms) for lock release on linux, to get rid of this error.

From sqlite-command, I can use for example (4 sec):

```
sqlite> .timeout 4000
sqlite>
```

I've started many processes which make select/insert/delete, and if I don't set this value with sqlite-command, I sometimes get :

```
sqlite> select * from items where code like '%30';
Error: database is locked
sqlite>
```

So what is the default value for .timeout ?

In Perl 5.10 programs, I also get sometimes this error, despite the default value seems to be 30.000 (so 30 sec, not documented).
Did programs actually waited for 30 sec before this error ? If yes, this seems crasy, there is at least a little moment where the database is free even if many other processes are running on this database

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect($database,"","") or die "cannot connect $DBI::errstr";
my $to = $dbh->sqlite_busy_timeout(); # $to get the value 30000
```

Thanks!

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/220617/109937 seems relevant. That says it depends on the client. So that'd be your DBD::SQLite. But there is no value set in there either, orin the XS file.

Comment: `$dbh->sqlite_busy_timeout` can also be used to set the timeout by passing it as a parameter.

Comment: [`sqlite3_busy_timeout`](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/busy_timeout.html) is the SQLite API function that's called as a result. It notes that setting a timeout of `0` disables timeouts, and it indicates that `PRAGMA busy_timeout; ` command can be used as an alternative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default busy timeout for `DBD::Sqlite` is defined in [`dbdimp.h`](https://metacpan.org/source/ISHIGAKI/DBD-SQLite-1.66/dbdimp.h) as 30000 milliseconds. You can change it with `$dbh->sqlite_busy_timeout($ms);`.

The `sqlite3` command line shell has the normal Sqlite default of 0; that is to say, no timeout. If the database is locked, it errors right away. You can change it with `.timeout ms` or `pragma busy_timeout=ms;`.

The timeout works [as follows](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/busy_timeout.html):

> The handler will sleep multiple times until at least "ms" milliseconds of sleeping have accumulated. After at least "ms" milliseconds of sleeping, the handler returns 0 which causes `sqlite3_step()` to return `SQLITE_BUSY`.

If you get a busy database error even with a 30 second timeout, you just got unlucky as to when attempts to acquire a lock were made on a heavily used database  file (or something is running a *really* slow query). You might look into [WAL mode](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html) if not already using it.